# File.Exist method couldn't find a file in C#

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have a C# code where I am checking if file exist at server location then do some operation. It works fine on local machine . But on server when it try to see the file exist , it returns false and couldn't able to find the file even though file is present at same location. If I do IISReset and run the same program again then it works . Here is my code

mspath is variable who is holding a server location path .

```
if (File.Exists(msPath))
{
    int length = msPath.IndexOf(companyName);
    string path = msPath.Substring(0, msPath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the file and also confirmed that the path is correct?

Comment: Are you making sure your msPath is absolute path?

Comment: Yes .Path is correct . I have even ping the path from server and file is present at that location

Comment: The path is probably ok but has the IIS IUSR account correct permissions to the folder and file?

Comment: Could [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401284/file-exists-returning-false-from-a-network-share) help ?

Comment: I found different issue related to file . It needs IISreset at the end of program.